# Is it possible to use JNI native Threads invoking a Java method (callbacks) to update Swing UI components?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, image-processing, java-native-interface

I'm developing an application for video processing using GStreamer and OpenCV. The task is to fetch images from an OpenCV source push/pull them into an GStreamer pipeline (does the converting and decoding and I have to stream the video data later) and process the images in an Java language environment.

So I build a native framework in C managing this task. Now I use JNI to access my C-Library, and I've attached the executing GStreamer main loop to the JVM. There are some threads unrelated to the image processing for which I use the SDL library but there are not calling any Java methods. Apparently it works so far. I get the raw images into Java and I also can display its byte data using a `ByteBuffer` (created on the native side) `get` method and a `System.err.println`.

The problem is to display these images somehow in a GUI. I use the Swing framework for my graphical environment.

So I made a quick and dirty image view by extending an `JPanel` as I usually would and which usually works when I use Java only.

I override the `paint` method to draw the image using the `Graphics.drawImage` method. The image is generated by copying the raw data, delivered by the native callback, into an integer array and then assign this integer array to a `MemoryImageSource`. I use the `createImage` method (of JFrame) to get an `Image` object. Everything returns apparently valid references. No exceptions are thrown and all. At least none visible to me.

Tried several ways as well as just use a byte array for the `MemoryImageSource` none generated images so far. The data however is there and I can read it!

I can copy the data, display the byte data but I'm unable to get an displayable image showing up in my custom `JPanel` view area. It is like the images are completely black or transparent or something.

This problem really beats me, I have no Idea how to convince this thing to work. I assume there are several problems with the threading here. But I have no further resources for this specific scenario.

What am I doing wrong, or better how to do it the right way.

**Additional**:
The application also sometimes just crashes or the GUI freezes if I change the size the window, so I avoid doing this for the moment. So there are problems with the native threads.

Comment: Any updates to the UI should take place on the event dispatch thread, most commonly effected by calling SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable).  This means that your image data must exist in a scope that is available to the producing thread and the event dispatch thread.

Comment: I did this on my last Test ... no success ...

Comment: You will certainly have no success unless you do it on *every* test.

Comment: The memory is allocated native and deallocated as soon as the callback returns. I wanted to access it directly using the `ByteBuffer.array()` method but it didn't work  (not supported) so I allocate another array in java and copy the data using get(). There should be two copies of each image.

Comment: So after you do the copy, verify the copy is accurate.  Then, prior to painting in the UI, again verify the data to ensure you are using the same data as the previous verify step.  If everything checks out up to that point, then the problem is getting your data into a format that the UI can actually paint.

Comment: Data is there. You can use `MemoryImageSource` bound to a array of linear aligned RGB samples (stored in a byte array). This ImageSource generates the images. It works before too with the same method. Outputs on native side and on the Java side tell me there is the same Data transfered in each call of the callback. I do much more. I copy the data into an Integer array (instead of a byte array) placing the color values at the right places(as it works usually) then assigned to the MemoryImageSource and generate the Image. I get an Reference in return so I assume the data correct.

Comment: In Java Swing, you don't override paint.  You override paintComponent.

Comment: So I checked my arrays again and there is data in them. I also overrided paintComponent only. I does not work.

Comment: "it does not work" is a poor description of the situation.  What do you mean by "as it works usually"?  Do you mean that process works in other situations, or that you *sometimes* get the expected results?

Comment: I would recommend passing a known quantity (red square on a white background) from the native code to the UI thread, to remove data variation as a potential issue.  Also show each native update in a separate component, to isolate speed and latency issues.  Once you get the known data displaying properly, you can re-attach the original data stream.   You might even go one step further and spawn your own native thread so that you have control over the frequency of data updates (unless you can do that in GStreamer via other means).

Comment: You need to include a code example in your question.  Without at least pseudo code, it's hard to say whether you're not simply making an error that you're overlooking, like passing the native buffer to another thread instead of copying it into a shared buffer (which could cause a crash).

Comment: I going to write an more specific answer today in the evening... since the comments is way to short for this type of text ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the OpenCV-Library to access cameras installed on a system. I grab the dimension, color information and the BGR-Samples from each grabbed frame and let a GStreamer AppSrc pull images into a video processing pipeline according to the frame rate the whole thing was initialized with. The initial pipeline looks like this:

OpenCV-Camera --> AppSrc --> VideoRate --> ffmpegcolorspace --> AppSink

Its going to be more complex soon but right now this is how it looks like.

The AppSink calls a function on the Gstreamer "new-buffer" signal (among some other no related to my problems matter). These callback implementations invoke Java object functions delivering the image color and dimension as well as its sample buffer. So this as brief information about what I'm doing.

Now to my problem:

It seems I solved my problem. I now use another way to create my images and now it works.

Instead of using the memory image source like so:

```
//constructor, callback whatever
imageSource = new MemoryImageSource(data.width,data.height,rawdata,0,data.width);
...
//Paint method of a JFrame or what ever ...
...
image img = createImage(imageSource);
setBounds(100,100,img.getWidth(null),img.getHeight(null));
createBufferStrategy(2);

BufferStrategy strategy = getBufferStrategy();

Graphics gr = strategy.getDrawGraphics();           
gr.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
gr.dispose();

strategy.show();
```

I use these few lines which work for me right now:

```
int[] nBits = {8, 8, 8};
ComponentSampleModel sampleModel = new ComponentSampleModel(DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, width, height, channels, width * channels, new int[] {2, 1, 0});
ColorSpace colorSpace = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB);
ColorModel colorModel = new ComponentColorModel(colorSpace, nBits, false, false,Transparency.OPAQUE,DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);

DataBufferByte db = new DataBufferByte(new byte[][] {buffer}, buffer.length);

WritableRaster raster = Raster.createWritableRaster(sampleModel, db, new Point(0, 0));
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(colorModel, raster, false, null);
```

buffer denotes herein raw byte samples array I get throught my method invoked from the native side.

I also ran into several other problems using swing like a freezing UI or a crash throwing these error messages:

```
[xcb] Unknown request in queue while dequeuing
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
java: ../../src/xcb_io.c:178: dequeue_pending_request: assertion »!xcb_xlib_unknown_req_in_deq« failed.
```

This is because I used the `UIManager.setLookAndFeel()` method to set the windows appearance to the systems default. I didn't link this with the problem because I didn't know that Swing uses the native UI framework if you use default system "Look And Feels". Removing this resolves the problem. My research lead me to a forum [post](http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/java-look-and-feel-uimanager-setlookandfeel-ui/#post-3965857) (in german) which describes this occurring on Java only (no native part) on Linux (Ubuntu) machines while the same application works on windows machines without modification. So removing it solved my problem. I think my "image not showing up issue" is somehow related to this but I don't know and I don't care since I works now.